# Security risks of PermitUserEnvironment in ssh

Tags: security, ssh, environment-variables

I've read quite a few posts regarding the use of `PermitUserEnvironment` and the file `~/.ssh/environment` in order to pass env variables to an ssh shell. The official [sshd docs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config%205) and a few other resources allude to some security risks of doing this.

> Enabling environment processing may enable users to bypass access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such as LD_PRELOAD.

What are the likely security issue of activating `PermitUserEnvironment`? I was looking to hold DB connection details in these environment variables, is this advisable?

Comment: I filed a bug report with the OpenSSH project, asking them to add a few words to the sshd_config man page, clarifying this issue: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2317

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, if you're not trying to do anything fancy with user access restrictions -- that is, if you're offering interactive shell access -- there are probably zero *additional* security risks in allowing use of the `.ssh/environment` file, since anything the user could accomplish with that file they could also do interactively in their shell.

> Enabling environment processing may enable users to bypass access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such as LD_PRELOAD.

If you are using SSH forced commands to limit what people can do via ssh (for example, if you're restricting people to only using `sftp` or `scp`), allowing someone to set environment variables such as `LD_PRELOAD` (or possibly even `PATH`) would allow them to hijack your restrictions by replacing basic library calls with their own code.  On the other hand, if you're creating the `.ssh/environment` on behalf of your users and they are not otherwise able to manage it, your risks are relatively small.

Without knowing more about your particular use case it's hard to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: I'm only allowing access to the server from 2 or 3 trusted parties (devs within our own organisation) via their rsa keys. So from what you're saying it sounds ok

Comment: From your answer, I take it that I should not lose any sleep about security implications of enabling this option if all my ssh accounts provide full bash access (no sudo). Correct?

Comment: That's correct. If you're providing full bash access, people can already set whatever environment variables they want.